# How do I mimic Thunderbird's username/password encryption in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, thunderbird

I'd like to add new email accounts to Thunderbird via an external application. The simplest way seems to be to edit the `moz_logins` table located in `signons.sqlite`. However, Googling did not yield any information on how Thunderbird encrypts this data, only that it is possible for it to be decrypted.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that file contains the saved passwords for web forms of webpages. You'd be better off touching cert8.db, key3.db or secmod.db which are NSS files that contains the credentials for the web servers. Beware, these are potentially encrypted by a master password. I believe you should be able to find some documentation about that.